# Is it possible to create an object of type Promise<Promise<T>> in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise

All these 3 statements return a `Promise<T>` instead of a `Promise<Promise<T>>`

```
// first  
const foo = Promise.resolve(Promise.resolve(42))

// second
function bar() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            resolve(42)
        }));
    })
}

// third
function baz() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    resolve(42)
                }, 1000)
            }))
        }, 1000)
    })
}

foo.then(console.log)  // 42
bar().then(console.log)  // 42
baz().then(console.log)  // 42
```

Is it possible to create a `Promise` which resolves another `Promise` in JavaScript?

Comment: What would a use case be for this?

Answer (score 2):

No.

If the resolved value of a Promise is another Promise then it will be adopted.

Comment: Is that actually true? In C# it's not uncommon to have `Task<Task<T>>` and to use double `await` to resolve them.

Comment: Yes, it's true, that's why I wrote it as an answer.

Comment: Note that there is an existing request at [microsoft/TypeScript#27711](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27711) to either forbid `Promise<Promise<T>>` or to collapse it to just `Promise<T>` automatically.  It's still an open issue...  but it does indicate that, despite TypeScript letting you write the type, there's really no such thing in JavaScript that acts like  `Promise<Promise<T>>`.